# 木村さんの彼はどんな人ですか？

Tags: meaning, sentence

そのフレーズがあまりわかりません。誰のことを言ってるの？
答えは、英語か、簡単な日本語で、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: Not sure which part of the sentence is troubling you. Can you give us your translation for the parts you do understand?

Comment: What kind (of person) is Mr. Kimura? I don't get why there is the word "he" there.

Comment: 'He' is not the only translation of 彼: https://jisho.org/search/%E5%BD%BC

Comment: So, the new translation would be: What kind of person is Kimura's boyfriend?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: They say not to thank anyone, but thank you for sticking with me.